# Short Code for PHP string with variable

Tags: php, string, escaping

I have a query string that contains a variable like this

```
$field_name = 'features';
$value = '5';
$query = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE $field_name\_tid = '$value'";
```

My goal is to print out the `$query` like this `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE features_tid = '5';`
I put `\_` there hoping it would work as escape character, but it didn't work. Is there any way to achieve this without use methods like `". $field_name ."` and modifying original variable value?

Comment: Enclose the variable in `{}`  `$query = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE {$field_name}_tid = '$value'";`

Comment: See the [PHP docs on string quoting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Comment: You can also escape it.. $query = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE " . $field_name . "_tid = '$value'";

Comment: Do it as Michael states, but DO be carefull with that field_name: it shouldn't be user supplied, and if it is, it should be compared to allowed fieldnames i.e. whitelisted.

Comment: awesome, thanks guys. @Wrikken yea, I just put up there as an example. It's not user supplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE {$field_name}_tid = '$value'";
```

Answer (score 2):

yes:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE {$field_name}_tid = '$value'";
```